# How to refer to someone who has depression(A noun for someone who has depression)?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, nouns, medical

What do we call a person who is suffering from depression?

Usually I hear "X has depression" but can I say *"X is a 'depressive'"?

I have heard the word depressive used as a noun before; but I'm not sure if it is right.

We do use diabetic to describe someone who has diabetes, so is there a parallel word there?

Comment: I think the current preference is to avoid using any words of that form, and sticking to 'person with Y', because a person is still first and foremost a person.

Comment: @JessicaB You are right, in fact I have depression. I was just curious and in certain conversations (like support groups) it becomes redundant to say "we people with depression " over and over agian

Comment: Should we avoid "parent" and say "person with children" for the same reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have heard the word depressive used as a noun before but I'm not sure it is right.

Yes, it is right (especially in the plural). For example:

> Depressed mood is often associated with a variety of physiological maladies, and many depressives are burdened with an assortment of ailments ranging from migraine, colitis, and allergies, to endocrine disorders and menstrual disturbances. [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=NEU282Oo46cC&pg=PA29&dq=depressives)]

Comment: Link is to a book dating back over a quarter of a century, though; see my comment on Rathony's answer.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: Yes -- nouns like "depressive" and "diabetic" have [become less common in recent years](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=depressives%2Cdiabetics). But since the OP is specifically holding up "diabetic" as an example, and seeking a parallel word, I don't see that as a problem.

Comment: FYI, you can specify POS in Ngram [thus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=depressive_NOUN%2Cdiabetic_NOUN%2Cmelancholiac_NOUN&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 2):

***Edit***: as commented by Brian Donovan, the two words suggested below seem to be archaic. The best candidate could be a [***depressed person***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+depressed+person&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20depressed%20person%3B%2Cc0) or [***depressed people***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+depressed+person%2C+depressed+people&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20depressed%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdepressed%20people%3B%2Cc0) in plural which are more broadly used nowadays.

[***Melancholiac***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/melancholiac) is a person:

> suffering from melancholia or ***depression***: *He argues that the melancholiac's self-loathing disguises a hostility towards the lost, beloved object, indicating an underlying ambivalence towards it*.

[***Depressive***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/depressive) could also be used:

> A person suffering from or tending to suffer from ***depression***:
>   *Phase-advancing sleep may be a useful treatment for depressives who eschew medication*.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

[***Melancholia***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/melancholiac):

> a mental condition and especially a ***manic-depressive*** condition
>   characterized by ***extreme depression***, bodily complaints, and often
>   hallucinations and delusions

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Harking back as it does to late classical, medieval, and Renaissance humoral psychology, *melancholiac* strikes me as archaic to a fault. I did use to hear and read patients with what we now call *bipolar illness (bipolar* for short) termed *manic depressives,* but that too seems dated. My sense is that the discourse of psychopathology has intentionally trended away from nominating persons according to their diagnoses.

Comment: @BrianDonovan So is a *diabetic clinic* no longer kosher? Must we say *diabetes clinic*? How about *amputees*, *paraplegics* etc?

Comment: My comment addresses neither terms for modifying nouns such as *clinic,* nor terms for sufferers from any but mental illnesses.